# Белый экран при сборке на VUE CLI

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

пишу приложение на Vue.js исользую vue cli, на Дев сервере ошибок нет, но после сборки белый экран, перечитал кучу статей, пробовал методы разные та-же ситуация.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: ''
}
```

Что нужно вписать чтоб заработал Vue собраный?

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.vue --version.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в браузере запрашивается ли ваш  app.js

Comment: Та же самая ерунда( Посмотреть удается через serve -s dist, а при загрузке на гитхаб пусто(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вероятно пытаетесь запустить файл `dist/index.html` напрямую. В руководстве `Vue-cli` есть информация по этому поводу:

> Каталог `dist` предназначен для обслуживания `HTTP`-сервером (если не
> задали `publicPath` относительным значением), поэтому не сработает если
> напрямую открыть `dist/index.html` через `file://` протокол. Самый простой
> способ предпросмотра вашей сборки для `production` локально —
> использовать статический файловый сервер `Node.js`, например `serve`:
>
> ```
> npm install -g serve
> # флаг -s означает запуск serve в режиме одностраничного приложения (SPA)
> # который решает проблему маршрутизации, описанную ниже
> serve -s dist
> ```

Таким образом, исходя из того, что ваш проект успешно собран (успешно выполнена команда `build` в `Vue-cli`), установите пакет `serve` (флаг `-g` означает, что пакет будет установлен глобально и может быть использован вами в любом вашем проекте для локального предпросмотра):

```
npm install -g serve
```

И находясь в корневой директории вашего проекта, запустите [локальный предпросмотр](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/deployment.html#%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80) используя команду:

```
serve -s dist
```

Если эти два условия выполнены правильно, вы должны в вашем терминале, где запускали вышеуказанные команды, увидеть отчет о том, на каком хосте и порте запущен предпросмотр. Скопируйте URL и вставьте в адресную строку браузера, чтобы просмотреть работу вашего проекта.